# Is there an easy way to tell if a public address was derived from an hd key?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, deterministic-wallets

Assuming you know the hd key's private & public info, and you have a given address is there an easy way to know whether or not that address is derived from said hdkey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than just deriving a ton of potential keys and checking whether they correspond to the address, no. There is no mathematical relation between keys in a HD keychain that allows you to determine whether they are in that keychain.

Comment: Yikes. Okay so I suppose I'll need to check my database if an address receives value. Thanks!